# Configuring Tomcat 7 + JSF 2 + Weld

Tags: jsf, tomcat7, cdi

I'm trying to create a new project using tomcat 7.0.27 + JSF 2.1.7 + Weld 1.1.8

After I add Weld to the project when I try to open a page I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:345)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:154)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

And if I add JSTL 1.2 to the project JSF stops rendering (if I open the page source on browser its the same thing from the IDE).

Any ideias?

Thanks a lot,
Phillip

Comment: This isn't an answer, but have you looked at TomEE? You're building part of your own web profile container. Why not just use one that's already built and properly integrated?

Comment: This project runs fine on Glassfish, but I prefer using Tomcat since it has a cheaper hosting.

No faces-config.xml, I'm using JSF 2 defaults.

Comment: Are you using jsps or XHTML files for the views?

Comment: Adding a faces-config.xml solved the problem -.-; Answer the question that I'll give you the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make sure you have faces-config.xml in WEB-INF